# Admob mediation dependency not downloading in gradle

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I'm using libgdx to make an android game and am now trying to add ads networks (facebook and chartboost) through admob mediation. I'm using the following to integrate facebook sdk

```
implementation ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'){
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer'
}
```

If I don't use the exclude group exoplayer then I get an error

```
 Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.3
```

For now excluding it helps. Now for the mediation I'm using as described in the documentation

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
 implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:chartboost:7.0.1.0'
```

But I get the error

```
 Failed to resolve:com.google.ads.mediation:chartboost:7.0.1.0
 Failed to resolve:com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same thing for chartboost, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sadly no.. I ended up using Admob alone..